# Как остановить выполнение функции, после истечении определенного времени?

Tags: php

Как остановить выполнение функции, после источенного n-го времени и вернуть ответ, что время истекло.

Пробовал try catch отследить, но в данном случае ошибку не видит.

```
set_time_limit(1);

try {
    sleep(4);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $file = fopen("log.log", "a+");
    fwrite($file, $ex->getMessage() . "\n");
    fclose($file);
}
```

Или есть другие варианты? подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Времени или циклов? Если время, то у вас все есть sleep в коде остановит выполнение на указанное кол-во секунд, потом выводите  что хотите.

Comment: @RuslanSemenov мне не нужно каждый раз останавливать функцию при помощи sleep. Задумка такая - если моя функция не успевает выдать нормальный результат, то выдается сообщение, что время истекло

Comment: Так сделайте итерации с задержкой и проверкой на выполнение условия.

Comment: не совсем понял для чего ставить задержки при каждой итерации

Comment: Ну сделайте цикл на 10 шагов, при каждом выполнении ставите паузу на 1 секунду, после окончания секунды проверяйте выполнено ли ваше задание и выходите если удачно. Если за 10 циклов не было удачного результата вы ведите ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственное решение, что я нашёл это - смотрим время в начале выполнения функции и запоминаем. Периодически при выполнении функции смотрим (текущее время минус первоначальное) и если оно превышает заданное, то выдаём необходимый return

Буду рад, если есть ещё решения для данной проблемы